# Calling visual C++ code from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I got stuck with a "ref" keyword which is applied to the class in .cpp file. 
I want to access a method which is marked as __clrcall. Can u tell me what ref
keyword used for in visual c++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "short short" version is that a "ref class" is a managed class.  You can't have member variables of a managed type (.NET Library objects, like StringBuilder or TCPListener) in a class that is not declared "ref" -- that is, unmanaged classes cannot contain managed objects.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

*A ref class or ref struct can inherit from zero or more managed interfaces and zero or one ref types. A value class or value struct can only inherit from zero or more managed interfaces.*

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w96b5h7(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Still confused please elaborate